# Unable to set arbitrary value for a background in TailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a React web app where you can create rooms and assign custom colors to them (hex), this color is then shown as a small circle beside the name of the room.

According to [this documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#arbitrary-values):

> ### Arbitrary values
>
> If you need to use a one-off `color` value that doesn’t make sense to
> include in your theme, use square brackets to generate a property on
> the fly using any arbitrary value.
>
> ```html
> <p class="bg-[#50d71e]">
>   <!-- ... -->
> </p>
> ```

I did the same thing when displaying the color beside the room's name:

```html
<span
  className={`bg-[#${room.bgColor}] mr-4 h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full`}
  aria-hidden='true'
/>
<span className='truncate'>{room.name}</span>
```

When I inspect the page, this is the resulting HTML:

```html
<span class="bg-[#f43f5e] mr-4 h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="truncate">Room Name</span>
```

But somehow the color is not showing up. I only see the name of the room but no colored circle beside it. Using something like `bg-green-500` seems to show the circle but I don't want to use predefined colors from the TailwindCSS theme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using an inline `style` instead:

```html
<span
  className="mr-4 h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full"
  aria-hidden='true'
  style={{ backgroundColor: `#${room.bgColor}` }}
/>
<span className='truncate'>{room.name}</span>
```