# Hover function in tailwind css is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So I have a code in ReactJS using Tailwind CSS that goes `hover:bg-${color}-200 bg-${color}-100` which works fine. However, when I change it to `hover:bg-${color}-300 bg-${color}-200`, the `bg-${color}-200` part works but the hover part doesn't. I have tested `hover:bg-${color}-400` and it works just fine.

Why don't the hover work when it's 300? Is there anyway that I can make it work?

I have also tried 50, 500, 700, 800, 900 and 950 and they don't work as well. What works are 200, 400 and 600. Is there a reason for this?

I'm not sure if this additional information can help - I've placed the code in a `tr` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

`hover:bg-${color}-200`, `bg-${color}-100`, `bg-${color}-200` and `hover:bg-${color}-400` work by coincidence since the resulting class appear as unbroken strings in other code scanned by Tailwind.

To resolve your problem, you could consider using full class names in definitions, like:

```
const color = 'bg-red-200 hover:bg-red-300';

<div className={color}>
```

Or you could consider [adding the possible classes to the `safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes):

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  // …
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^bg-(red|green|blue)-200$/ },
    {
      pattern: /^bg-(red|green|blue)-300$/,
      variants: ['hover'],
    },
  ],
  // …
}
```