# How to use dynamic column options grid-cols tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I build custom Table component.

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

const StyledTable = ({children, role})=>{
    return <div role={role} 
        className="border border-color-grey-200 text-sm bg-color-grey-0 rounded-md overflow-hidden">
        {children}
    </div>
}

const CommonRow = ({children, columns, className, role, as=""})=>{
    return <div 
        role={role}
        as={as}
        className={ classNames( 
        `grid grid-cols-[${columns}] gap-1 items-center transition-none `, className)}
        >
        {children}
    </div>
}

const StyledHeader = ({children, columns, role, as})=>{
    return <CommonRow 
            role={role}
            as={as}
            className="text-color-grey-600 px-10 py-6 bg-color-grey-50 border-b border-b-color-grey-100 uppercase tracking-wider font-semibold" 
            columns={columns}>{children} </CommonRow>
}

const TableContext = createContext()
const Table = ({children, columns})=>{
  return <TableContext.Provider value={{columns}}>
    <StyledTable role="table">
      {children}
    </StyledTable>
  </TableContext.Provider>
}

const Header = ({children})=>{
  const {columns} = useContext(TableContext)
  return <StyledHeader role="row" columns={columns} as="header">
    {children}
  </StyledHeader>
}

Table.Header = Header

export default Table
```

When I put this component my page columns dont access. Here div-s on Header show by row. When I open layout bar browser dont show columns. Show only rows.  Interesting thing when I add

```
0.6fr_1.8fr_2.2fr_1fr_1fr_1fr
```

worked. But I change some option dont work. For example:

```
0.4fr_1.8fr_2.2fr_1fr_1fr_1fr
```

this dont access.

```
<Table columns="0.6fr_1.8fr_2.2fr_1fr_1fr_1fr">
                    <Table.Header>
                        <div></div>
                        <div>Cabin</div>
                        <div>Capacity</div>
                        <div>Price</div>
                        <div>Discount</div>
                        <div></div>
                    </Table.Header>
                      
                </Table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute instead:

```html
<Table columns="0.6fr 1.8fr 2.2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr">
```

```
const CommonRow = ({ children, columns, className, role, as="" }) => {
  return <div 
    role={role}
    as={as}
    className={classNames( 
      'grid gap-1 items-center transition-none ',
      className
    )}
    style={{ gridTemplateColumns: columns }}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
}
```