# Dynamic Classes not applying to Tailwind CSS grid layout when using with breakpoints in Angular application

Tags: html, angular, responsive-design, tailwind-css, media-queries

I am using Tailwind CSS in my Angular application. In my grid layout I am trying to dynamically add values for `col-span-`. If I use dynamic values without using any media query breakpoints like lg, md etc. they work fine. But when I try to add these values with breakpoints, they don't seem to apply.
Here is my Tailwind css grid:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let app of (dashboardApps | async); let index = index; let firstItem = first">
        <div class="flex justify-between py-2 px-2 bg-[#eae4d8] rounded-md col-span-12 relative">
          <p class="mt-2 text-lg font-semibold">{{app.name}}</p>
          <a *ngIf="userRoleCheck == true" [routerLink]="['/modules/add-module', app._id]" [queryParams]="{parentID: app?._id || ''}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-[#F15B41] text-white no-underline hover:text-white text-base hover:bg-opacity-80 hover:transition-colors">+ Add new app</a>
        </div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!app.submodules || app.subsubmodules?.length == 0; else showApps">
          <div class="h-5"></div>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #showApps>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let appdata of app?.submodules; let i = index; let firstModule = first; let last = last;">
            <ng-container *ngIf="appdata?.status !== 3">
              <grid-top-app
                (deleteModule)="showDialog($event, template)"
                [appData]="appdata"
                class="col-span-full lg:col-span-{{ appdata?.layout?.colWidth || '4' }}"
              ></grid-top-app>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="appdata?.status == 3">
             <ng-container *ngIf="currentUser?.id == appdata?.createdBy">
              <grid-top-app
                (deleteModule)="showDialog($event, template)"
                [appData]="appdata"
                class="col-span-full lg:col-span-{{ appdata?.layout?.colWidth || '4' }}"
              ></grid-top-app>
             </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
```

As you may see, this is where I am applying dynamic styles `class="col-span-full lg:col-span-{{ appdata?.layout?.colWidth || '4' }}"`
They work fine if I don't use breakpoints but otherwise they don't apply. And If I inspect my DOM, I can clearly see that the dynamic class is present on the selector/html tag (screenshot below)
[image]

But in the view I see `col-span-full` being applied (screenshot below)
[image]

I want these styles to apply for all breakpoints (lg, md, xl etc.). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Comment: I just viewed it and according to the answer there I cannot use a syntax like ``col-span-`` + value. I need to write full class names based on the dynamic value I receive. I'll try it out and see If I can make it work

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Consider applying `grid-columns` via the `style` attribute instead.