# How to calculate Height in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm currently facing an issue with calculating my container height, and it doesn't seem to be affecting the UI as expected. I've tried to set the height using the following code, but it's not taking effect:

```
h-[calc(${SectionHeight}px-45px)]
```

Where Section Height is The Parent Container Height i am calculation it becz also  this Piece of code doesnt work

```
h-[calc(100%-45px)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute instead, like (assuming this is React):

```
<div style={{ height: `calc(${SectionHeight}px - 45px)` }}>
```

Or, since `SectionHeight` is in pixels, we can subtract 45 in JavaScript-land like:

```js
<div style={{ height: SectionHeight - 45 }}>
```

Since we pass a `number` type, React will automatically append the `px` unit.

Comment: Actually thanks for reply but this issue is resolved