# Next.js 13 client component not loading all tailwind classes

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13

I have created basic next 13 app with button as client component:

```
"use client";

const Button = ({
  children = "",
  variant = "filled",
  background = "white",
  color = "black",
  className = "",
  onClick = () => null,
}) => {
  let buttonClasses = `rounded-lg ${className}`;
  switch (variant) {
    case "outline":
      buttonClasses += ` border border-${background} text-${background}`;
      break;
    case "filled":
      buttonClasses += ` bg-${background} text-${color}`;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return (
    <button className={buttonClasses} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

In the tailwind config file i have this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      textColor: {
        white: "#FFF",
        black: "#000",
        ...colors,
      },
      colors: {
        primary: "#00aeef",
        secondary: "#ee3444",
        backgroundGray: "#f6f8f9",
        ...colors,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

When I create a button with background set to primary or secondary it doesn't load that css, but when I make just simple div in my page js with class name background-primary all buttons with background primary have that class and work fine but still ones with secondary color don't work.
Also text color is not working but other classes such as width and rounded-lg work perfectly fine.

I tried using basic colors like blue, black etc but it also didn't work.
Here is an example of my button usage:

```
return (
    <div className='flex w-100 px-20'>
      <div className='w-2/12'>
        <Button background='primary' color='white' className='font-bold w-full'>
          Btn1
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className='bg-backgroundGray w-7/12'>
        <nav>
          
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className='w-3/12 flex'>
        <Button background='blue' color='white' className='font-bold w-1/2'>
          Btn2
        </Button>
        <Button
          background='secondary'
          color='white'
          className='font-bold w-1/2'
        >
          Btn3
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using a style mapping like:

```js
const BG_STYLES = {
  filled: {
    white: 'border-white text-white',
    blue: 'border-blue text-blue',
    // …
  },
  outline: {
    white: 'bg-white',
    blue: 'bg-blue',
    // …
  },
};

const TEXT_STYLES = {
  white: 'text-white',
  blue: 'text-blue',
  // …
};

const Button = ({
  children = "",
  variant = "filled",
  background = "white",
  color = "black",
  className = "",
  onClick = () => null,
}) => {
  let buttonClasses = `rounded-lg ${className}`;
  switch (variant) {
    case "outline":
      buttonClasses += ` border ${BG_STYLES.outline[background]}`;
      break;
    case "filled":
      buttonClasses += ` ${BG_STYLES.filled[background]} ${TEXT_STYLES[color]}`;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return (
    <button className={buttonClasses} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Otherwise, you could look at [safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) all the possible classes you may need like:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /^(bg|border|text)-(white|blue)$/,
    },
  ],
  // …
}
```