# React + tailwind, not applying the color in the browser

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

can someone help me to understand wtf im doing wrong?
Its a notification message:
i have a variable:

```
 const notificationStyle =`bg-${bgColor}-500 text-lightgrey text-lg border-solid border rounded-3xl p-4 mb-4`;
```

if SuccessNotification apply bg-green-500, if ErrorNotification apply bg-red-500.
If I inspect in the browser the element has the class, BUT in the browser the color is not rendered.
If i change ${bgColor} to green, directly, he renders the color green, and if i put the variable back, it works, but if i restart the application, it doesnt.

to be more specific: `<div class="bg-green-500 text-lightgrey text-lg border-solid border rounded-3xl p-4 mb-4">Welcome Eduardo</div>`
but in the browser its white.

`<div class="bg-red-500 text-lightgrey text-lg border-solid border rounded-3xl p-4 mb-4">wrong username or password</div>`
in the browser its red.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Notification = ({ message, bgColor }) => {
  if (!message) {
    return null;
  }

  const notificationStyle = `bg-${bgColor}-500 text-lightgrey text-lg border-solid border rounded-3xl p-4 mb-4`;

  return (
    <div className={notificationStyle}>
      {message}
    </div>
  );
}

export const ErrorNotification = () => {
  const errorMessage = useSelector(state => state.notifications.errorMessage);
  return <Notification bgColor="red" message={errorMessage}  />;
}

export const SuccessNotification = () => {
  const successMessage = useSelector(state => state.notifications.successMessage);
  return <Notification bgColor="green" message={successMessage}  />;
}
```

I cleaned my cache with control + F5, and it worked, but now, its not working anymore.
I honestly dont have any idea what is happening,
i tried microsoft edge, the same problem.

Can someone explain me what is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names in definitions, like:

  ```
  const Notification = ({ message, bgColor }) => {
    if (!message) {
      return null;
    }

    const notificationStyle = `${bgColor} text-lightgrey text-lg border-solid border rounded-3xl p-4 mb-4`;

    return (
      <div className={notificationStyle}>
        {message}
      </div>
    );
  }

  export const ErrorNotification = () => {
    const errorMessage = useSelector(state => state.notifications.errorMessage);
    return <Notification bgColor="bg-red-500" message={errorMessage}  />;
  }

  export const SuccessNotification = () => {
    const successMessage = useSelector(state => state.notifications.successMessage);
    return <Notification bgColor="bg-green-500" message={successMessage}  />;
  }
  ```
- [Safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) the classes you will use, like:

  ```
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      'bg-red-500',
      'bg-green-500',
      // etc.
    ]
    // Or
    safelist: [{ pattern: /^bg-(red|green)-500$/ }]
    // etc.
  }
  ```

Comment: I honestly appreciate your time and dedication to help me, I was totally lost and couldnt understand, because my 'logic' was flawless, if i inspect the element, IT IS RIGHT, but as Im a newbie, I lack technical knowledge.
Once again, thank you!