# Next.js TailwindCSS classes added via props not rendering properly in map loop

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

```
const DummyData = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    title: "lorem ipsum",
    desc: " ",
    cta: "Explore Service",
    ctaUrl: "/",
    theme: "#E4F8ED",
    btnTheme: "#4F9D73",
    links: [
      {
        title: "Project lorem ipsum Tools ",
        url: "/",
      },
      {
        title: "Augmented lorem ipsum ",
        url: "/",
      },
      {
        title: "lorem ipsum and Forecasting ",
        url: "/",
      },
      {
        title: "Data lorem ipsum Analytics ",
        url: "/",
      },

      {
        title: "Quality Control lorem ipsum Analysis  ",
        url: "/",
      },
    ],
  },
  // more data
]

// jsx

<div className="text-left w-full bg-amber-100 mb-5 mx-auto   grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3">
  {DummyData.map((item, index) => (
    <div className={`bg-[${item.theme}] p-5`} key={item._id}>
      <div className="p-4 h-full flex flex-col justify-between">
        <div>
          <p className="text-[#101828] font-bold text-[30px] leading-[36px]">
            {item.title}
          </p>
          <p className="text-[#101828] text-[12px] font-normal my-4 leading-[18px]">
            {item.desc}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="my-8">
            {item.links.map((list, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                className=" border-b-[1px] w-fit border-[#DBDBDB] py-2 "
              >
                <Link
                  href={list.url}
                  className="text-[#101828] text-[14px] font-medium leading-[22px] w-fit  flex transition-all hover:opacity-75  "
                >
                  {list.title}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <Link
            href={item.ctaUrl}
            className={`text-[#fff] text-[14px] font-medium leading-[22px] w-fit py-2 px-8 flex transition-all hover:opacity-75  bg-[${item.btnTheme}]`}
          >
            {item.cta}{" "}
            <Icon
              path={mdiArrowTopRight}
              style={{ marginLeft: "0.5em" }}
              size={1}
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

The above code works ideally but sometimes few classes won't work like the button background css for two button in this case?

Why so and how to fix it ? also better way to do something like this ?
attached Image for reference below.
the button in automation and document understanding card is not rendering the background css but it does for the speech & languague card.
[image]

observed the code for an hour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could look at using the `style` attribute like:

```html
<div className="p-5" key={item._id} style={{ backgroundColor: item.theme }}>
```

```html
<Link
  href={item.ctaUrl}
  className="text-[#fff] text-[14px] font-medium leading-[22px] w-fit py-2 px-8 flex transition-all hover:opacity-75"
  style={{ backgroundColor: item.theme }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the class is added correctly in HTML but just isn't doing its job. This is because Tailwind "needs to know" which classes are in use. So, the ones you are using somewhere else in your code are working but not the others.

If you really want to use this concatenation, you need to add all those possible classes to the Tailwind safelist. In `tailwind.config.ts` (or `.js`) add them like:

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  // other existing configs
  safelist: [
    'bg-[#4F9D73]',
    'bg-[#E4F8ED]',
    // ... and all the other ones not working... 
  ],
  // ...
}
export default config
```