# Variables in classes don't work with tailwind css + react to change a color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

does anyone know why, when using Tailwind CSS in a class and attempting to use a state variable (in this case, I am using React), the color changes in the DOM, but nothing changes in the user interface?

```
interface CustomButtonProps {
    color: string;
    borderRadius: string;
    buttonText: string;
    colorText: string;
}

const CustomButton: React.FC<CustomButtonProps> = ({ color, borderRadius, buttonText, colorText }) => {


    return (
        <button className={`bg-[${color}] rounded-${borderRadius} px-4 py-2 text-[${colorText}]`}>
            {buttonText}
        </button>
    );
};

export default CustomButton;
```

Inspecting the page, the color of the text and the background of the class do change, but on the interface side, nothing happens.

Is it a Tailwind issue? Is there something I should do in the Tailwind setup file? Because if I manually set it in the code as bg-[#000], it works, but if I set it dynamically, in this case, I'm using a color picker, the state variable changes, the class changes too, but on the interface side, nothing happens. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

I want to change the colors of my button in real-time as my state variables change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names, like:

  ```
  const CustomButton: React.FC<CustomButtonProps> = ({ color, borderRadius, buttonText, colorText }) => {
    return (
      <button className={`${color} ${borderRadius} px-4 py-2 ${colorText}`}>
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    );
  };

  // …

  <CustomButton
    color="bg-[#123456]"
    borderRadius="rounded-sm"
    colorText="text-[#FEDCBA]"
    buttonText="Foo"
  />
  ```
- Using the `style` attribute, like:

  ```
  const CustomButton: React.FC<CustomButtonProps> = ({ color, borderRadius, buttonText, colorText }) => {
    return (
      <button
        className="px-4 py-2"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: color,
          borderRadius: borderRadius,
          color: colorText,
        }}
      >
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    );
  };

  // …

  <CustomButton
    color="#123456"
    borderRadius="10px"
    colorText="#FEDCBA"
    buttonText="Foo"
  />
  ```

Comment: for myself best tailwind solution for this is to use [Class Variance Authority](https://cva.style/docs)