# TailwindCSS classes not being recognized when using a switch function in my Laravel 10 model

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css

I'm using a switch function in my Listing model to control the TailwindCSS classes based on the field value. I've tried adding all the Tailwind color classes to the tailwind.config file but that didn't work.  When I inspect the elements on the page, the classes are populated to the page, but not recognized.

**Listing.php**

```
...
public function getStatusClass()
{
    switch ($this->listing_status) {
        case 'Draft':
            return 'slate';
        case 'Active':
            return 'green';
        case 'Sold':
            return 'red';
        case 'Under Contract':
            return 'orange';
        case 'Pending':
            return 'purple';
        default:
            return 'gray'; // Default color for unknown status
    }
}
...
```

**components/partials/listing-desktop.blade.php**

```
@foreach($listings as $listing)
    ...
    <td class="px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap">
        <span class="bg-{{ $listing->getStatusClass() }}-100 text-{{ $listing->getStatusClass() }}-800 text-xs font-medium mr-2 px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded dark:bg-{{ $listing->getStatusClass() }}-900 dark:text-{{ $listing->getStatusClass() }}-300">{{ $listing->listing_status }}</span>
    </td>
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names, like:

  ```php
  public function getStatusClass()
  {
      switch ($this->listing_status) {
          case 'Draft':
              return 'bg-slate-100 text-slate-800 dark:bg-slate-900 dark:text-slate-300';
          case 'Active':
              return 'bg-green-100 text-green-800 dark:bg-green-900 dark:text-green-300';
          case 'Sold':
              return 'bg-red-100 text-red-800 dark:bg-red-900 dark:text-red-300';
          case 'Under Contract':
              return 'bg-orange-100 text-orange-800 dark:bg-orange-900 dark:text-orange-300';
          case 'Pending':
              return 'bg-purple-100 text-purple-800 dark:bg-purple-900 dark:text-purple-300';
          default:
              return 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300'; // Default color for unknown status
      }
  }
  ```

  ```php
  @foreach($listings as $listing)
      ...
      <td class="px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap">
          <span class="{{ $listing->getStatusClass() }} text-xs font-medium mr-2 px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded">{{ $listing->listing_status }}</span>
      </td>
      ...
  @endforeach
  ```
- [Safelisting the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) you will use:

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^bg-(slate|green|red|orange|purple|gray)-100$/ },
      { pattern: /^text-(slate|green|red|orange|purple|gray)-800$/ },
      {
        pattern: /^bg-(slate|green|red|orange|purple|gray)-900$/,
        variants: ['dark']
      },
      {
        pattern: /^text-(slate|green|red|orange|purple|gray)-300$/,
        variants: ['dark']
      },
    ]
    // …
  }
  ```

Comment: The first option may still not work if you haven't configured the content paths properly. For example, the [recommended config for Laravel](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel) will not scan files in the app/ folder