# Vue.js Component Only Renders Background Colors from a Subset of Tailwind CSS Colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a card component:

```
<template>
  <div
    class="z-50 flex w-[15vw] flex-col items-center justify-center gap-5 rounded-md border-2 border-gray-300 bg-[#f3f3f3] p-5 transition-all duration-300 hover:scale-105 hover:font-bold"
  >
    <div class="w-[100%]">
      <div
        :class="color"
        class="flex w-fit items-center justify-center rounded-3xl px-2 text-sm text-white"
      >
        {{ collection }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="flex w-[100%] flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2 text-2xl font-thin text-black"
    >
      <div class="italic">{{ question }}</div>
      <div class="w-[100%] rounded-3xl border-2 border-gray-200"></div>
      <div class="font-semibold">{{ answer }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  collection: String,
  question: String,
  answer: String,
  color: String
})
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

and how i use it:

```
   <UsersFavoriteCard
        :color="color"
        collection="AsyncJs"
        question="does it work"
        answer="yes"
      ></UsersFavoriteCard>
```

```
const color = computed(() => {
  const colors = ['orange', 'blue', 'green', 'amber', 'rose', 'teal']
  const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)].toLocaleLowerCase()
  const randomRange = 300
  const color = `bg-${randomColor}-${randomRange}`
  console.log(color)
  return color
})
```

the function works, fine, it generatas for example:
bg-red-300
bg-blue-300
bg-amber-300

but from all of the color, only blue and green are applied.
So if i load the page and the color is:
bg-blue-300 or bg-green-300

the card element has this color.

but when the output is bg-red-300 or bg-rose-300 which are valid tailwind colors, the element has no color and i have to refresh the page so the blue or green are choosen.
If i manually set color to
color='bg-red-300'
it works.
Why it is so inconsistent? Why valid tailwind color generated by function doesnt work, but set manually works but green and blue works all the time?

I tried many examples using tailwind colors, but all set manually works, but generated by functions it doesnt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pass variable as a className to tailwind-css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535186/why-cant-i-pass-variable-as-a-classname-to-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider one of the following methods to rectify your predicament:

- Use full class names in definitions, like:

  ```js
  const color = computed(() => {
    const colors = ['bg-orange-300', 'bg-blue-300', 'bg-green-300', 'bg-amber-300', 'bg-rose-300', 'bg-teal-300']
    const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)].toLocaleLowerCase()
    console.log(color)
    return color
  })
  ```
- [Safelist the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) you might use like:

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      'bg-orange-300',
      'bg-blue-300',
      'bg-green-300',
      'bg-amber-300',
      'bg-rose-300',
      'bg-teal-300'
    ],
    // …
  }
  ```

  Or

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      {
        pattern: /^bg-(orange|blue|green|amber|rose|teal)-300$/,
      },
    ],
    // …
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The way Tailwind CSS works, it only scans and compiles readily available class names ([official docs reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)). So essentially, it does not recognize your:

```
bg-${randomColor}-${randomRange}
```

Going by your implementation, I can see you want to randomly pick from your array of colors and use the 300 palette variant. My advice is to use the [Tailwind Safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) feature, so that Tailwind can always compile those colors in the final CSS file by default. Here's what you need to add to your `tailwind.config.js`

```
       module.exports = {
          // other config options here...
          safelist: [
            'bg-orange-300',
            'bg-blue-300',
            'bg-green-300',
            'bg-amber-300',
            'bg-rose-300',
            'bg-teal-300',
           // You can add more Tailwind classes you wish to compile by default e.g lg:text-red-100, md:justify-center, etc. 
           // Just about any Tailwind classname really...
          ]
        }
```

Hopefully this helps.